# How to check CSS loaded size in Angular Application

Tags: css, angular, sass

Hope you all doing great.

I am using SCSS and Bootstrap in my Angular Application and as we know once Angular app runs, it converts these SCSS files to CSS version of it.

How can I check CSS file size generated as a whole for application as I need to show some reports for optimization tasks.

Any idea. I tried googling and here on Stack Overflow but couldn't find required solution. I can't even see any CSS file in Network tabs of Browsers.

Any Suggestion?

Comment: You can check it in your bundle.

Comment: I am kind of little new to it. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Which bundling tool are you using? Webpack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didnt find any css generated in Network like above answer but I did a trick.

I went to webpack folder and there I found one generated CSS. ( Searched through a random CSS Selecto ).

I right clicked and saved it on desktop. If you check the properties of this CSS file, it shows the size in KB.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using Angular CLI for your project, which uses webpack internally...

Once you build a project. A `dist` directory is generated in the project root. Take a look into it and you'll find all the `.js` and `.css` bundles it might have generated.

Note - The size will vary based on what kind of build you do. For a production build, the sizes are going to be minimal, for other kinds of builds, if any, the sizes may differ.

Comment: Yes I can see SCSS folder under assets directory but I can't see any CSS files those are converted from SCSS.

Comment: One question. Currently SCSS folder size 90KB  around. Once this SCSS will be converted to CSS, i think size would be bigger right ?

Comment: You have to check the `dist` directory for bundled and converted files. Not `assets`

Comment: Assuming Angular-CLI. Follow these steps. Open Terminal > Go to Project Root > npm run build. It'll generate a dist directory. `cd dist` >  `ls -la`. see sizes.

Answer (score 1):

You should go first in the Networks tab then reload the page. Once you reload it, click on CSS filter then you would see all the list of CSS included in your app, with the file size. [image]